# PFLogInViewController customization

Tags: ios7, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

When subclassing PFLogInViewController for customization.
How do I change the character string saying "Parse" to something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the info you need in this tutorial:
https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views

Comment: Right, this is the first thing I looked at, before starting to use PFLogInViewController. But I hadn't realized that this "Parse" piece of text was in fact the logo. My mistake :)
Never mind. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Actually I have another problem I ran into and do not find the answer in the tutorial you mention.
The PFLogInViewController takes all the display on the device and this is not good, because even if the user cannot log in, he should still be able to use the other parts of the app. So I want to leave open the tab bar at the bottom of the app so the user is not locked in the PFLogInViewController screen.

Answer (score 1):

after creating instance of parse's login controller

```
let loginViewController = PFLogInViewController()
```

you can access logo this way:

```
loginViewController.logInView?.logo
```